# Can't access SQLite via PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm having an issue accessing SQLite over PHP. I can access SQLite directly from the command line via:

```
 sqlite3 filename
```

but this script which I have in /var/www/script will only display the PHP version:

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
echo "<br>";
echo sqlite_libversion();
?>
```

I'm following this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitephp/

Is this the section in php.ini that I should be looking at? pdo.ini didn't seem to contain anything relevant and that is the only other ini file I can find.

```
[sqlite]
; http://php.net/sqlite.assoc-case
;sqlite.assoc_case = 0

[sqlite3]
;sqlite3.extension_dir =
```

Comment: check that sqlite is enabled in the SAPI version of the php.ini file.

Comment: have found the file, having trouble finding the SAPI version though

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in either mode (cli or via web browser) will show you where the .ini file is being loaded from.

Comment: Server API Apache 2.0 Handler

Comment: no. you want the `Loaded Configuration File` and `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` and `Additional .ini files parsed` stuff. THAT'S where you have to enable sqlite.